# Can we use to_char( ) with GROUP BY in HQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

while executing the following query using Hibernate

```
select to_char(vdadCloseDate,'yyyymm'), count(*) from RmDashboardAccountDataBe where 1=1  and vdadRmId in('MK13','MK11') GROUP BY TO_CHAR(vdadCloseDate,'YYYYMM')
```

I'm getting the following exception,

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Is there any way to handle this issue?

Comment: This is an Oracle error message. As far as I can tell, query looks all right. Are you **sure** that this one returned that error?

Comment: yes, I'm pretty sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is "pure" Oracle SQL (i.e. not HQL) which looks exactly like your query (I had to use different table and column names, though):

```
SQL> select to_char(hire_date, 'yyyymm'), count(*)
  2  from employees
  3  where department_id in (10, 20)
  4  group by to_char(hire_date, 'yyyymm');

TO_CHA   COUNT(*)
------ ----------
200309          1
200508          1
200402          1

SQL>
```

So - yes, it works OK.

This is a link to [HQL Group by clause](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-grouping) which also suggests that such a query is perfectly valid (have a look so that I wouldn't have to copy/paste its contents over here).

That's why I asked whether you're sure that this is the query that returned ORA-00979 error. As you responded that it is, huh, I wouldn't know what to say ...

Comment: That's a shame :(  I don't have a way to test HQL, but - as I said - documentation says that GROUP BY is valid in HQL. Really strange ... Hopefully, someone else will be able to assist. Good luck! **[EDITED]** Hey! Where did your comment go?!?

Comment: sorry! I don't know how now the query worked. Thanks a lot for supporting me.

Comment: Miracles happen, now and then :) OK, I'm glad it works now!